# Link prefetching redownload page in Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, prefetch

I'm trying to speed up a Moodle instance (an LMS). I know for certain that users will likely go on their last accessed course, so I'm trying to use link prefetching to download the course page in advance:

```
<link href='https://moodleexample.io/course/view.php?id=3' rel='prefetch' />
<link href='https://moodleexample.io/course/view.php?id=3' rel='prerender' />
```

In Chrome, it works rightly. But Firefox shows a strange behaviour. It correctly downloads the web page using prefetch, but when I request the course page, it downloads it again:

[image: Wireshark dump of http requests]

You can see from the Wireshark screenshot that it requests the course page again (at time 12.79).

Why does this happen? I tested it on an unencrypted Moodle, and it shows the same unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Moodle's "fault". They're dynamic pages, so it puts cache headers that block caching of content.

Using the power of Nginx, I rewrote those headers when getting the `X-moz: prefetch` from Firefox:

```
if ($http_x_moz ~ ^prefetch$) {
    more_set_headers 'Cache-Control: private, max-age=60'
    more_clear_headers 'Pragma';
}
```

In the `php` location. I have also conditionally inserted the prefetch tag only for firefox, using server side browser detection.